# Clearing Placed Labels in Tkinter

Tags: python, function, tkinter

So I have a currency which is increasing (that system is working fine).  The first part updates the label every 100 ms.  I have another button which triggers the second function which is supposed to clear the labels from the first.  It sets `home_status` equal to `0` which should in theory run `Money.place_forget()` to clear the code.  I have tested each part individually and it works but when I put the clears inside the `elif` statement it doesn't. It does not give me any errors, it just simply doesn't do anything (it does print `END OF UPDATE HOME` so the `elif` *is* triggered).

Any suggestions?

```
def updatehome(self):
    print("UPDATE HOME")
    global buy_button, home_status, currency
    MoneyLabel = Label(self, text = "Money: ")
    MoneyLabel.place(x = 5, y = 70)
    Money = Label(self, text=currency)
    Money.place(x = 50, y = 70)
    if (home_status == 1):
        self.after(100, self.updatehome)
    elif (home_status == 0):
        print("END OF UPDATE HOME")
        Money.place_forget()
        MoneyLabel.place_forget()

def clearhome(self):
    print("CLEAR HOME")
    global home_status
    home_status = 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are creating ten labels every second, all stacked on top of each other, but you are only deleting the very last label you create.